# Gradle cannot resolve github dependency

Tags: android, github, gradle, jitpack

I had created a library for android, pushed it to gitub, and build it with Jitpack. 
Now, my problem is, that Gradle cannot resolve my dependency 
(failed to resolve com.github.[…])
I tried to import the default android project from jitpack - it works.
So my question is, what is wrong with my lib?
https://www.github.com/ludev-studio/colorpicker-android

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Its my own library. I do not want to use another. What have i to do to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your Jitpack dashboard, you can see that all of your builds have failed: https://jitpack.io/#ludev-studio/colorpicker-android

Fix the errors in the logs, and then your library will be resolved correctly.

Comment: I had. I tried with Jitpack sample project - it works. The Isue is in mine.

Comment: Found your issue. Edited answer

Comment: It's looking for a pom.xml file and not finding it. Make sure it is included in your GitHub repository.

Comment: There isn't a pom.xml in my project!